# Java Socket-Server to Query MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, sockets

Im developing a desktop application using Java & MySQL, i would like to apply 3-tiers Architecture for my application.

After many reading and searching about RESful,JSON,Web service ... etc.
I found a very cool & simple solution for really Enterprise application, the idea is as follow:

1. Client: A Thin Client with GUI.
2. Server: A Socket Server, that has the logic of the application & The MYSQL Queries.
3. MySQL: As A database server.

Server, will be responsible about connecting,getting data from MYSQL & send it to client.
Client, will only send message to request data (SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE).

All (SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE) Statements will be in the server side only.

- HOW CAN I DO IT?
- WHAT DATA TYPE SERVER WILL RESPOND TO THE CLIENT?
- THERE IS NEARLY NO PROBLEM IN DOING A SIMPLE CLIENT/SERVER COMMUNICATION SENDING AND RECEIVING, BUT IT STILL CONFUSING ME SINCE I STILL LEARNING ABOUT IT.
- Any Error exception in the the server side should be represented in the Client side.
- What we will use:

  1. Java SE.
  2. MySQL Database.
  3. Socket-Server-Client.

Comment: CAN WE GET RID OF ALL THE CAPITAL LETTERS PLEASE IT IS GENERALLY CONSIDERED THE SAME AS SHOUTING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is **too broad**. You will get many conflicting answers. From what you write, it's clear that you will not be able to distinguish between good and bad advice. Also, while I honestly keep my fingers crossed, **you will fail**. It's clear that you lack experience in most of the technologies you describe, and you will not be able to learn them all at once and deliver the project. Unless you are superhuman.

To keep the answer constructive (although I voted to close the question): use Glassfish + JPA + remote EJBs + application client. They are tutorial-rich technologies and they get you really close to what you want to achieve (RPC is easier than REST, and Java serialization is easier than any JSON/XML binding - especially for arbitrary object graphs)
 - exceptions will propatate,
 - any serializable type will be transfered
 - you get a working IDE, easy installation and good support for MySQL and all the other technologies out of the box (Netbeans 7.4)

Comment: Yes i'm superhuman, and can get it if i found the right resources, i guess you who don't have working around this, i came here to learn.

Comment: The problem is that you have all the resources you need to learn - the Internet is full of documentation. If you actually want to LEARN anything, it will take years from the level you are at. If you want someone to just give you a working solution - then the question is too broad. Try the constructive part of my answer, I really think it is realistic. You will not understand what's really happening, but you might complete your project.

Comment: I have a lot of ready socket application, i can use any one to accomplish my project, but i want to understand. I can do Client/Server Using Socket sending/Receiving from scratch, but what I'm looking for is Server which control all my SQL transaction within LAN, i need advice for that, there is no Documentation over internet telling you how to Query Database By using Socket server, the socket server responsible about Contacting to database and return the result to Client. I can Use RESTful+JSO+Servlet+Tomcat, but i want to Java SE only in the whole project.

Comment: @fdreger is offering good advice. Although it is possible to write three-tier applications using Java SE, this is a low level approach. There is more support for solving 3-tier problems in a 3-tier framework such as Java EE (Spring is an alternative.) Even with Java EE there are different ways to solve this problem. RESTful+JSO+Servlet+Tomcat is one way, but again it is a low-level approach that will be harder than using an EJB container. A modern Java EE container will solve the remoting problem with little more than an "@Stateless" annotation on the remote (stateless session bean) class.